# SQL-Statement: Calendar event related to contact

Tags: mysql, sql, vtiger, heidisql

I am in the process of developing an SQL query to let HeidiSQL display the calendar entries and connected contacts.

The appointments are included in the vtiger_activity table and the contacts in the vtiger_contactdetails table. A connection exists through the table "vtiger_crmentity".

```
SELECT a.subject
     , a.activitytype
     , a.date_start
     , a.due_date
     , a.time_start
     , a.time_end
     , d.firstname
     , d.lastname
  FROM vtiger_activity a
  LEFT 
  JOIN vtiger_crmentity c
    ON c.crmid = a.activityid
  LEFT 
  JOIN vtiger_contactdetails d
    ON d.contactid = c.crmid
 WHERE a.due_date >= '2019-05-18' AND a.date_start <= '2019-05-23'
```

Result of Query: it shows the dates in the time period but in the columns where it should show the contact is everywhere only NULL The query I need it for a Android App. I expected firstname and lastname, because the data exists.

Does anyone know where I have my mistake?

Ever thank you for your help

[image: Vtiger 7.1.0 and HeidiSQL]
[image: ER-Diagram]

Comment: It seems a little odd that an activityid and a contactid would be the same thing - but hey, it's not my schema

Comment: What do you mean by that? The preferences are from vtiger. I only use it.

Comment: activityid = crmid = contactid - This seems odd, but it's not necessarily wrong.

Comment: @Strawberry is totally correct. That second join is wrong. because you are basically saying you want to get the information of a contact that has the same id as the activity, which will never occur. That's why you get nulls for the contact info. The relation between activities and contacts is not stored on the vtiger_crmentity table. I know the schema but I can't remember the name of the table. The relation between activities and contacts is many to many so there must be an intermediate table that stores pairs of activity and contact ids.

Answer (score -2):

Your `LEFT JOIN`s are in the wrong order.  If you want the names, they are from the details table, and that should be the first table in the `FROM`.  You will also need to move the conditions to the `ON`.

Something like this:

```
SELECT d.firstname, d.lastname, a.subject, a.activitytype
       a.date_start, a.due_date, a.time_start, a.time_end
FROM vtiger_contactdetails d LEFT JOIN
     vtiger_crmentity c
     ON d.contactid = c.crmid LEFT JOIN
     vtiger_activity a
     ON c.crmid = a.activityid AND
        a.due_date >= '2019-05-18' AND
        a.date_start <= '2019-05-23';
```

Comment: With your suggestion it shows me the firstname and lastname. But all other fields are set to _NULL_ .

Comment: @Flips87 . . . Because there are no matching activities during the period.

Comment: Hmmm, Wed 22, Event: "Beitrittsverhandlungen". That suits the period. The mistake is probably somewhere else.

Comment: @Flips87 . . . Perhaps `c.crmid = a.activityid`.  That seems like unusual column names to equate.

Comment: Perhaps because it perpetuates what appears to be gibberish (activityid = crmid = contactid) - although again, I'm uncertain as to whether its the anonymity or the negativity which prompts your incredulity.

Comment: It was me who did the downvote (not sure how to not make it anonymous). But yes, its because of the activityid = contactid impossibility. That will just not work. I'm 100% sure on this. Not only because it's logically flawed but because I know Vtiger database and know it just does not make any sense. I downvoted the answer to prevent someone taking it as an option. @Strawberry you should downvote it too.

Comment: But important is not the column name, but the preferences. 
Then there must be another table join. So far, I have not seen any. In vtiger 7.1.0 there are 523 tables